# How to create a portable gpgme directory for C/C++ projects

Tags: linux, encryption, c++, libraries, public-key-encryption

This question is probably quite basic knowledge but here it is. I want to integrate public key encryption, preferably using gpgme, in my projects but the computers running it will not always have gpgme installed and I will need to run make there. How can I have a directory with installed in it to insert it on my projects?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does openssl have to do with [GnuPG Made Easy (GPGME)](https://www.gnupg.org/software/gpgme/index.html)? It's not a requirement, is it?

Comment: It is not, I was looking for the same thing with openssl at the time I posted this question so I mistakenly wrote openssl. I corrected it now.

Comment: Ah ok. The gpgme tarball is only 3.6MB, or 19 extracted... what's wrong with just copying it to wherever you need to make projects? Or at least the required files?

Comment: Probably nothing, but I have not done anything similar in the past so I am not sure about it. If a simple 'cp' will do the job, this question is redundant, but I worry about config files, installation paths etc.